# Return tables range address with original style

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range, defined as below:

```
Call Test (Range("tblInsRep[#all]"))
Sub Test (rngSRange As Range)
.
.
.
End Sub
```

I need analysis above address (`tblInsRep[#all]`) to define the given table address is including Header or not, with this code: (If `rngSRange` declared as `String` argument)

```
Call Test ("tblInsRep[#all]")
Sub Test (strSRange As String)
    Dim rngSRange As Range
    Dim HControl As Boolean 'Header Control

    Set rngSRange = Range(srtSRange)

    HControl = IIf(InStr(1, strSRange, "[#All]") > 0, True, False) 
.
.
.
End Sub
```

Thus, I want using first approach for `Test` subroutine, because it is more clean and brief.

How can I return the `tblInsRep[#all]` string from `rngSRange` in below:

```
Call Test(Range("tblInsRep[#all]"))
```

Calling:

```
Sub Test (rngSRange As Range)
    Dim HControl As Boolean 'Header Control
    Dim strSRange As String

    strSRange=...(rngSRange)

    HControl = IIf(InStr(1, strSRange, "[#All]") > 0, True, False) 
.
.
End Sub
```

*Screen-shot of my worksheet's table*:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to achieve, but I am not able to understand. Can you upload a sample of your datam what is your table, and what you want the result of your code to be ?

Comment: With regard, I revised my question. Sure, I will upload...

Comment: Not sure, do you mean something like : `strSRange = rngSRange.Address(False, False, xlA1)` ?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Comment: So Address method with each ReferenceStyles, returns same as `GU4:HK214` and not return `tblInsRep[#all]` which that I need.

Comment: You are sending a `Name`d range ? and you want to get the name of it ?

Comment: These addressing is used for `Table` objects which comes after Excel 97. For example these Formula: `=tblInsurance[@[Column1]]`, refers to Column1 column of current Row of tblInsurance Table.

Comment: @ShaiRado, Would you please answer my question?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve here. share a screen-shot of your Excel sheet, mark what `Range` you are trying to pass to `Sub Test`, and what should be the desired result

Comment: [https://ibb.co/cuLq65](https://ibb.co/cuLq65)

Comment: @ShaiRado, I replaced the clear and distinct picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Public Function test(rngSRange As Range, tablename As string)

    Dim strSRange As String, checktbl As String

    checktbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tablename).HeaderRowRange.Address

    strSRange = rngSRange.Address

    test = IIf(InStr(1, strSRange, checktbl), True, False)

End Function
```

Go to your sheet and write for ex: `test(J4:J5;"Table3")`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, or your final goal, byt this is too long to put as a cooment, so I am putting it here (I will delete it later).

What you have (according to your screen-shot) is a VBA object reffered to as `ListObject`.

If you want to define your table with VBA, you can use the code below:

```
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim strSRange As String

' set the ListObject Table
Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblInsRep")

strSRange = Tbl.Range.Address ' <-- this gets the address of the entire Table's range
```

I am not sure what is the purpose of getting a `String` with `"tblInsRep[#all]"`.

Let me know what you intend to do with it, maybe we can find a better solution.

Comment: @ShahiRado,  I replaced the clear and distinct picture. Please check this, may understandable more..

Comment: I want give `tblInsRep[@All]` as a string value (`"tblInsRep[@All]"`) in `Test` subroutine and assign that to `strSRange` variable.

Comment: @MGae2M I understood that part (you wrote it at least 3 times already), my question what do you need `"tblInsRep[@All]"`` for ? what will you do with it ? I can't follow the logic of wanting to get this `String` from a range you define with that name ???

Comment: Unfortunately not work!  with `debug.Print strSRange`, the value `$GU$4:$HK$214` returned.

Comment: @ShahiRado I was tell about, in original question. Please note this line `HControl = IIf(InStr(1, strSRange, "[#All]") > 0, True, False)`

Comment: @MGae2M I am reading your post and comments, you are not reading mine. I saw `HControl = IIf(...` line, my question, what is the purpose of your code ? what should `HControl` return ?

Comment: If passed range is a table without Header and total, appropriated address been` tblInsRep` ~ `Range("tblInsRep")`. Thus if passed range to Test subroutine, which that a table contains Header row and Total, appropriated address been: `tblInsRep[@All]` ~ `Range("tblInsRep[@All]")`

Comment: @MGae2M you can check the number or `Rows` in the range and see if they match the total number of rows in table

Comment: @ShahiRado, I want give table range address as `tblInsRep[@All]` when this address name passed to a subroutine, in that subroutine from that range. Exacty i'm not reach my answer, but above answer is solve my problem with skape! same approach.